# dig lists "parent servers" in authority section

Tags: domain-name-system

Question: Is it normal that dig lists the "parent servers" and .com until a domain is fully propagated?

I just signed up with dnsmadeeasy but I get this when I dig the domain, which looks wrong

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/n5bv9.jpg]

The domain in question is masseffect3blog.com - when I dig gamerant.com another domain that is using dnsmadeeasy then the authority section gives me the correct DNSmadeeasy nameserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; if no authority is found for a domain, the authority for the domain is assigned to the root.  Since you were seeing this, it means that the name server delegation config in the domain registration was not yet active.  Looks good now, though.